# Sharing instance of class between other classes in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm trying to figure out the best way to share an instance of a class between two other classes that depend on it.

Say I have these classes:

```
class A
{
    public A(B b, C c) {}
}

class B
{
    public B(IDFactory factory) {}
}

class C
{
    public C(IDFactory factory) {}
}

interface IDFactory
{
    D GetD();
}

class D {}
```

And for each instance of `A`, I want the `D` used by `c` and `d` to be a single instance of `D`. When I create a new instance of `A` (say using a factory), I want `c` and `d` to share a *new* instance of D.

So far I've figured that using a custom lifestyle that uses a context (using [this](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles) cool library) might be the best approach. So I would do something like this:

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
[.. standard container registration stuff ..]
container.Register(Component.For<D>().LifeStyle.Custom<ContextualLifestyle>());

IAFactory factory = container.Resolve<IAFactory>();
using (new ContainerContext(container))
{
    A a = factory.GetA();
}
```

Now the problem I have with this is that I have to define the context at the point where I use the factory. Ideally this concept that `D` is semi-transient and should have a single instance per instance of `A` would be configured in the container when I register all my types. Another issue is that the context needs an instance of the container itself, which goes against the Three Container Calls pattern.

Can anyone suggest a better way of setting this kind of thing up, either using Windsor or with a better architecture. Also bearing in mind that D might be quite deep in the class heirarchy i.e. `A -> B -> C -> E -> F -> G -> D` and I want to avoid passing `D` all the way down the tree.

Comment: I think you have a Leaky Abstraction somewhere. Why are you injecting IDFactory into B and C? This strongly signals that B and C will be creating multiple instances of D during their lifetimes, but then you ask how to configure Castle so that you always get the same instance. It would make more sense to simply inject a D instance into B and C.

Comment: You're right that's pretty much what I want to do. How would I go about injecting the same instance of D into B and C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to share the same instance of D between b and c dependencies of A, then this should be enough:

```
class A
{
    public A(B b, C c) { }
}

class B
{
    public B(D d) { }
}

class C
{
    public C(D d) { }
}


...
container.Register(Component.For<D>().LifeStyle.Custom<ContextualLifestyle>());
A a = container.Resolve<A>();
```

If your IAFactory is implemented using container.Resolve you can use that instead of a direct call.

Also, if you are only resolving one "top level" component, you can omit the explicit creation of the context.

Comment: also if I Resolve top level of dependency graph omitting context creation, shared component will be created multiple times. It seems you cannot avoid to explicit create the context

Comment: @Cristiano: you are right. That was not the intended behavior. I will try to fix it, but in the meantime you can work around this by configuring your top level component to also use ContextualLifestyle (I just tested it and it worked without explicitly creating the context)

Comment: That's great. I tested for my case and it seems working fine: very useful specially since I'm using GuyWire approach to extract graph root... have to set explicit context creation would be a shame... Thanks a lot!