# Castle: using an existing (not single) instance for a lower-level dependency

Tags: castle-windsor

I have a model roughly like this:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork { }

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork { }

public interface IService { }

public class Service : IService
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public IService Service { get; set; }
}
```

And a configuration that could be like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<Service>()
                            .LifeStyle.Transient
                   Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>()
                            .LifeStyle.Transient,
                   Component.For<ViewModel>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

I need to resolve, at different points, two instances of ViewModel (I'm using a typed factory for this, but let's leave that aside for simplicity and assume I'm using the raw container)

The catch is that I need to resolve two instances of `ViewModel` **at different points** (from another ViewModel that knows about both), and they need to share the same `IUnitOfWork`.

So, something like this:

```
var vm1 = container.Resolve<ViewModel>();
//...later
var vm2 = container.Resolve<ViewModel>();
```

Now, it's very easy to share the **Service**. I'd just have to do something like:

```
var vm2 = container.Resolve<ViewModel>(new { vm1.Service });
```

But of course the actual model is more complicated (different ViewModels, with more Services each), so that's not an option.

I can pass the `UnitOfWork` to `Resolve`, but it doesn't get used by default (which makes sense). Is there any way to use that parameter (probably by registering a delegate somewhere) when resolving the second `ViewModel`?

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
var vm2 = container.Resolve<ViewModel>(new { UnitOfWork });
```

And get a `ViewModel` whose `Service` has that specific `UnitOfWork`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `ContextualLifestyle` coupled with a custom factory that kept a reference to the `ContainerContext`, in order to use the same one when resolving another `ViewModel`.

Comment: I did the same thing except with a child container which I can dispose on unit of work completion. The child container makes a nice context.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to share a component and you cannot set as singleton(rich client) or perwebrequest, you need to use Contextual lifestyle.
[check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247105/unitofwork-per-screen-in-a-client-app-using-windsor-castle) see my last comment to downoload contrib w/ Contextual Lifestyle

For you case I assume those 2 ViewModel will be used by 1 View... so View + UoW require Contextual Lifestyle

[check also this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849397/sharing-instance-of-class-between-other-classes-in-castle-windsor/4851416#comment-7332321) see comments at the end

Comment: Cristiano: I'm already using the contextual lifestyle, so all the services resolved *at the same time* share a UnitOfWork, and that works perfectly for composite views. In this case, each viewmodel is a wizard step, and they are resolved on demand.

Comment: your question was mentioning Lifestyle=Transient for uow. if you are already using contextual you should be all set. What am I missing?

Comment: fair question. I'm actually using ContextualLifeStyle for all components. The problem is, the Context ends after resolving the first VM. The idea of saving the Context crossed my mind but, even if doable, it would be a huge leak to the VM layer.

Comment: I ended up using a variation of contextual lifestyle, where the ViewModelFactory saves the context for later.